# A pattern to handle 0-n promises?

Tags: javascript, typescript, design-patterns, promise

I have to wait for 0-n promises. I currently check if I have 0, 1 or more promises and then either call no promise, one promise or Promise.All.

It seems poor style to me, that the `return this._createItemAndReloadItems(logItem)` part repeats three times. Is there a better pattern to achieve this?

```
public createItem( logItem: IInteractionLogItem): Promise<IInteractionLogItem[]> {
  const userPromises: Promise<{}>[] = [];

  if(logItem.Client && logItem.Client.AccountName){
    userPromises.push(this._ensureUser(logItem.Client));
  }

  if(logItem.AssignedTo && logItem.AssignedTo.AccountName){
    userPromises.push(this._ensureUser(logItem.AssignedTo));
  }

  if(logItem.ResolvedBy && logItem.ResolvedBy.AccountName){
    userPromises.push(this._ensureUser(logItem.ResolvedBy));
  }

  if(logItem.Referrer && logItem.Referrer.AccountName){
    userPromises.push(this._ensureUser(logItem.Referrer));
  }

  console.log("SharePointDataProvider.CreateItem: userPromises.length=" + userPromises.length);

  if( userPromises.length == 0) 
  {
    return this._createItemAndReloadItems(logItem);
  }
  else if( userPromises.length == 1) 
  {
    return userPromises[0].then( (value: {}) => { return this._createItemAndReloadItems(logItem); });
  }
  else 
  {
    return Promise.all(userPromises).then( (value: {}[]) => { return this._createItemAndReloadItems(logItem); });
  }
}
```

Is there a better pattern to deal with the dynamic amount of promises?

Comment: Well `Promise.all` works fine with empty and single-element arrays of promises as well, so why don't you use it in every case?

Comment: Oh I was confused by the Documentation, that required at least two parameters. Cool it works sweet as with an array with 0,1,n promises :-)

Comment: Which documentation did you read? It has one parameter only - the iterable.

Comment: IntelliSense, the AutoCompletion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I currently check if I have 0, 1 or more promises and then either call no promise, one promise or Promise.All

Consolidate into an *always* array and use `Promise.all`

e.g.

```
Promise.all([]) // 0
Promise.all([one]) // 1
Promise.all([one,two,three]) // n
```

## More

Basically when you have `0,1,n` values, use an array to consolidate the types, which is what an array is for.

Comment: Cheers, I was confused by the parameter list having at least two promises. It worked sweet as with 0,1,n promises :-) Cheers